# What is source of this form of Mahaprabhu?

Tags: chaitanya

[image]

What is the history of this six-armed image of Mahaprabhu? Kindly quote from proper source.

Comment: This is *shat bhuja murti* or the form of Lord Sri Caitanya with six hands, two of his own as he appeared in this world as a devotee Sri Caitanya holding a sannyasa staff and a pot, two hands of Lord Krishna holding a flute, and two hands of Lord Ramacandra holding an arrow and a bow. It's mentioned in the biographies of Sri Caitanya such as Sri Caitanya Caritamrita.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The *shad bhuja murti* form of Sri Chaitanya was revealed to Maharaja Prataparudra as described in Murari Gupta's Sri Krishna Chaitanya Charitra Mahakavyam:

> While the king offered praise, **Mahaprabhu, the protector of all sentient beings, displayed a radiant form of six-arms.** That form was embellished by copious ornaments, and it revealed His own greatness. It was wonderful, magnificent and filled with immense oppulence.
>
> Glory to the golden moon of Krsna Caitanya, who displays unbounded love, complete joy and ultimate charm. His eyes forever rove to and fro like bees in search of
>   honey. Glory to the forever-blissful Nityananda, who is Balarama Himself. His personality is filled with divine sweetness, and intoxicated by Gaura-prema His form is
>   sublimely personal and peaceful.
>
> **With His upper pair of hands, Gaurachandra brandished a bow and arrow, with
>   the middle pair He held an excellent flute to His broad chest, and the lower pair of
>   hands were held in a very graceful dancing posture.** Thus the monarch saw the
>   complete form of Gaurachandra, which was filled with love of Krsna.
>   (**Sri Krishna Chaitanya Charitra Mahakavyam, Canto 4, Chapter 16, Verses 13-15**)